# Setting limit into Datepicker

Tags: lightning, date-picker

I am presently using the following command to select date by the datepicker:-

`<ui:inputDate aura:id="startdate" format="MM/DD/YYYY" class="field" value="{!v.StartDate}" displayDatePicker="true"  />`

My requirement is to set a limit to the datepicker upto a year's data.

How do I set a limit to the datepicker to ensure that the user is not allowed to pick a date past the present date - 365 days?

Comment: You can write a validation which will check date range and if it does fall in the date range throw error.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I used the controller to set a limit...

Comment: Why not use lightning:input type date with mix, max? It disables of out of range dates as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchStartDate = component.get("v.StartDate");

    var result = new Date();
    result.setDate(result.getDate() - 365);
    var today = $A.localizationService.formatDate(result, "yyyy-MM-dd");

    if(searchStartDate<today){
        alert('The start date cannot be less than a year from the current date ');
        component.set("v.searchStartDate", null);}
```

This is the piece of code in controller to set a limit to the datepicker..